# Using PostgreSQL on Windows for production environment

Tags: windows, postgresql

We might need to deploy our new application that uses PostrgreSQL DB to the infrastructure where only Windows VMs are available. I have a question if it is fine to run the RDBMS server there, or we should insist on setting up a Linux VM. This might be complicated from business point of view as the company where we want to deploy it might not have engineers who can support Linux.
So I would like to know if:
1. It is ok to run production PostgreSQL server on Windows
2. If there any official statement regarding target running OS, couldn't find anything

I have found a somewhat similar question [Is PostgreSQL suited to one OS? Is it better on Linux than Windows?](https://serverfault.com/questions/222430/is-postgresql-suited-to-one-os-is-it-better-on-linux-than-windows) but it is quite old, so maybe something has changed since then.

Comment: I never saw any regardless to not use on windows but you can run inside a docker container base on linux on windows. It's not perfect but a option.

Comment: Thank you, I this is another option, but I think unfortunately it is also not as simple as just running the server on VM, as they already do with our older app on MS SQL Server